# finding the "boldtype" version of AA Nagari Shree L3 Devanagari font

Tags: fonts, bold, polyglossia

Dear fellow Texnicians,

I have a .ttf (true type) Devanagari font I would like to use when typing Sanskrit, which can be displayed in italics and boldfont when I am utilizing MS Word, but in the windows font folder it is displayed merely as 1 font, called AA_Nagari_Shree_L3.ttf, which is the regular font, so I don't know by which name to setup the bold variant and the italics font.

How can I access and use the bold version of the font?

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{fontenc,fontspec}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{sanskrit}

\newfontfamily\sanskritfont[
Path = /Windows/Fonts/,
Script = Devanagari,
Scale=MatchUppercase,
Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit
]{AA_Nagari_Shree_L3.ttf}

\newenvironment{dn}[1]{\sanskritfont#1}{}

\begin{document}\\

{\dn sugataan sasutaan sadharmakaayaan pra.nipatyaadarato 'khilaa.m"sca vandyaan|}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a font has no boldface variant, applications may fake it. This is also possible with `fontspec`, but it should be explicitly told to.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{sanskrit}

\newfontfamily\sanskritfont[
  Path = ./,
  Extension=.ttf,
  Script = Devanagari,
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
  Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit,
  BoldFont=*,
  BoldFeatures={FakeBold=2},
]{AA_Nagari_Shree_L3}

\newcommand\dn{\sanskritfont}

\begin{document}

{\dn sugataan sasutaan sadharmakaayaan pra.nipatyaadarato 'khilaa.m"sca vandyaan|}

\bfseries

{\dn sugataan sasutaan sadharmakaayaan pra.nipatyaadarato 'khilaa.m"sca vandyaan|}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I removed the useless call to `fontenc` and modified the definition of `\dn` (yours is quite wrong).

Answer (score 0):

While I did not find a direct way to solve this issue, I found a workaround for this particular problem:

Nagari Shree L3, when scaled at a factor of 1.3 seamlessly connects with Sanskrit 2003 font, which is a much bolder (Calcutta Style) font. Anyone wanting to switch between a "bold" and a "standard" Devanagari font, favouring, as I do, the beauty of AA Nagari Shree L3, thus can go about in this way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontenc,fontspec,xltxtra}


\setmainlanguage{english}\setotherlanguages{sanskrit,tibetan}

\newfontfamily\sanskritverse[
Script=Devanagari,
Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit,
Scale=1,
]{Sanskrit 2003}

\newfontfamily\sanskritfont[%needs to be called sanskritfont, see Wujastyk's blog 
Path = /Windows/Fonts/,
Script = Devanagari,
Scale=1.3,
Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit, %or any other mapping
%Conjuncts=Additional Conjuncts, 
%Character Alternates=Dha & Bha Curl Variants%
]{AA_Nagari_Shree_L3.ttf}

\newcommand{\dvb}[1]{{{\selectlanguage{sanskrit}\sanskritverse{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\dev}[1]{{{\selectlanguage{sanskrit}\sanskritfont #1}}}
    \newcommand\eng[1]{\begin{english}#1\end{english}}

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}
\dev{sugataan sasutaan sa}\dvb{dharma}\dev{kaayaan pra.nipatyaadarato `'khilaa.m"sca vandyaan|\\
sugataatmaja}\dvb{sa.mvaraavataara.m} \dev{kathayi.syaami yathaagama.m samaasaat||}%
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```